# Mysql query to find all in row when value in certain column appears

Tags: mysql

In my database table, I have a value denoted userID. The value user ID may appear multiple times. I am trying to write a query that will either return all data in the row of that table if the value in userID appears 3 or more times. Alternatively, a query that return a list of all userIDs that appear 3 or more times.

Here is what I have now:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    userID IN (SELECT 
            userID
        FROM
            myTable
        GROUP BY userID
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 2)
GROUP BY userID
```

This query kinda works, but some of the rows returned only have a single or double occurrence.

Any ideas on how I can modify this query so that it works?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You made things harder tnen they are, it's all simple:

```
SELECT 
   userID
FROM
   myTable
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(userID) > 2)
```

This is if you only need ID's, else you should use this in place of SELECT statement in your WHERE part

Answer (score 0):

Add the rest of your columns in the `GROUP BY userID` for all of the rows and youre super close with the list of userID's. This'll give you the UserID's:

```
SELECT userID FROM your_table
            GROUP BY userID
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

and this will be for all:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    userID IN (SELECT 
            userID
        FROM
            your_table
        GROUP BY userID
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3)
GROUP BY UserID, column_name1, column_name2
```